# Prevent form submit by pressing enter key on struts-dojo autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2, dojo, dom-events

I am trying to alter enter event for struts2-dojo autocomplete, where instead of submitting the form it should do some of my jQuery work.

I tried...

```
<s:form action="EmpAction">
    <sx:autocompleter label="Name" name="name" list="nameList" id="Name" showDownArrow="false" />
<s:textfield name="test" label="test" id="test"/>
</s:form>
```

and in jQuery...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
       $('#Name').key(function(e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert($(this).val());
            //and some jQuery code to get JSON and fill test textfield.
        return false;
        }
    });

}); 
</script>
```

but it still submits this form, I have used

> e.preventDefault();

in many cases and got success but here its not working.

Answer (score 1):

This code will work in your context

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
if(event.currentTarget != $("yourAutocompleteId")){
      event.preventDefault();
myPersonalFunctionCall();
}
else{$("yourAutocompleteId").one("onfocus", false);}

      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey sorry I missed few lines in my question and I just now added it. The missing part is the form tag and the autocomplete struts2-dojo tag. I tested your code and its working but in my case it should not submit the form when I hit enter in struts-dojo autocomplete tag instead it should do what that i had instructed inside jquery...

Comment: so what that has not been acheived yet ?

Comment: Enter key should work on autocomplete struts2-dojo tag and it should not submit the form but instead it should at least show alert "hi" message and after that it should not do anything.

Comment: i have updated my answer.You have to check if the enter event is fire from autocomplete.if so, then do nothing. else you have to prevent Default functionality.

Comment: Its not working again, the form is getting submitted. Whereas the first code of yours worked fine, where it did not submitted the form. This code `if(event.currentTarget != $("yourAutocompleteId")){myPersonalFunctionCall();}else{$("yourAutocompleteId").one("onfocus",false;}`, that which you added newly makes the call, to submit the form and I have no idea why it does.